# Jquery Mouse Up event didn't work with IE 11 scrollbar

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).mouseup(function () {
        console.log("mouse up");
    });
```

Anyone know why mouseup event didnt work for IE 11 when clicking on scrollbar?
It works ok for chrome and FF.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljam7hpk/

Comment: I think console.log() does not work in IE. You need to use alert() for that purpose.

Comment: No.. it is not true. IE 11 can run console.log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/783058/scrollbar-trigger-mousedown-but-not-mouseup and sadly Microsoft decided it's not important and won't fix it.

> However, this bug may not be a typical developer scenario particularly as more browsing happens on devices that are touch centric, we will not be able to address this bug during this release.
>
> We will continue to investigate the need for both mousedown and
> mouseup triggered by clicking the scrollbar.

Comment: a so "funny" response from Microsoft : " investigate the need for both mousedown and mouseup triggered" ... no seriously ? is there any investigation needed ? if there is a mousedown, there should be a mouseup when you release the button